# Trying to pass Color Hex as parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello So I am currently having some difficulty in working on a Site, I would like to have 10 preset color schemes and swap them with the click of an icon, rather than writing the function 10X I would rather do it once and each Icon with a link would simply send the parameters what I'm trying isnt working though, any indication as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated

The call to the function

```
<button type="button" onclick="themeOne(#D3649F,#000000,#666666)">Theme 1</button>
```

And now for the Function

```
function themeOne(p1,p2,p3) {

    var links = document.getElementById('slidebar').getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].style.color = p1;
    }


    var glyph = document.querySelectorAll(".blue");

    for (var i = 0; i < glyph.length; i++) {
        glyph[i].style.color = p1;
    }

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = p3;
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor = p2;
    document.getElementById("navbar2").style.backgroundColor = p2;
    document.getElementById("slidebar").style.backgroundColor = p2;
    document.getElementById("page-content").style.color = "#FFFFFF";
}
```

My concern is with what I am passing to the Variable as Im not sure if the "#' is considered an int or if I need to do something like just sending the numerical digits and follow up with something like:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + p3;
```

Comment: Provide the color codes in quotes `themeOne('#D3649F','#000000','#666666')`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple I must have been missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the parameters as strings.
this would result in changing the following:

```
<button type="button" onclick="themeOne('#D3649F', '#000000','#666666')">Theme 1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your console and enter `0xD3649F` in it.  You'll see the output `13853855` which is nothing particularly extraordinary.  It translates to a simple number as if you had written directly `13853855`.

You can convert a number into a hex string, but it would be more convenient for you to simply surround your hex value passed to `themeOne` in quotation marks, in other words the following:

```
<button type="button" onclick="themeOne('#D3649F','#000000','#666666')">Theme 1</button>
```

This is a string of course, but just like how width values generally contain units and require that the value be a string (i.e. `'150px'` instead of number `150`), it is perfectly acceptable to assign a string of a hex number for color values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi believe you need to have the colours as strings.... as in your function:

```
document.getElementById("page-content").style.color = "#FFFFFF"
```

So:

```
<button type="button" onclick="themeOne('#D3649F','#000000','#666666')">Theme 1</button>
```

might be the answer?

update: Yep, I tested it and this modification works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use css instead of doing that via javascript...

You should use Javascript only for switching from one theme to another...
here is an example:

```js
function themeCtrl($) {
  var select = $('#themeCtrl');
  var container = $('#container');
  
  var theme = 'theme-' + select.val();
  
  select.change(function() {
    var _theme = 'theme-' + select.val();
    
    container.removeClass(theme).addClass(_theme);
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(themeCtrl);
```

```css
.theme-default .text-success { color: green; }
.theme-default .text-error { color: red; }
.theme-default .text-danger { color: orange; }
.theme-default .text-info { color: cyan; }

.theme-inverted .text-success { color: red; }
.theme-inverted .text-error { color: green; }
.theme-inverted .text-danger { color: cyan; }
.theme-inverted .text-info { color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="themeCtrl">
  <option selected value="default">Default</option>
  <option value="inverted">Inverted</option>
</select>
<hr />

<div class="theme-default" id="container">
  <div class="text-success">TEXT SUCCESS</div>
  <div class="text-error">TEXT ERROR</div>
  <div class="text-danger">TEXT DANGER</div>
  <div class="text-info">TEXT INFO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I do in fact agree this looks like a much better option with more flexibility, the reason I am taking the route with Javascript is because I am working on my Senior Project and we are required to use ASP.Net MVC web App and Injecting Java Script into the main layout is far easier to deal with for my severe lack of experience with Visual Studio, not only am I stretched for time in getting this done in sprints, I am also required to develop my own personal application in Android studio, another foreign tool set :)